# MySQL query to join the same table

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join two SQL queries run on the same table. Result should contain common rows. I know MySQL does not have `INTERSECT`. I need to use `JOIN` I guess, but I am not sure how to when the SQL queries are run on the same table.

A sample query in answer would be great.

Comment: What problems occured when you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inner or cross join, so something like that:

```
select a.columnname
from table a
inner join table b
on a.key= b.key
where clauses
```

Comment: I want to run the queries on the same table. you have two different tables  'a' and 'b' in your answer

Comment: @911Rapid it's the same table, don't be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) is what you're looking for.
In order to refer the same table multiple times you need to use aliases:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM my_table AS t1
#                ^
#           this is alias
JOIN my_table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
#                ^
#           this is alias
```

The `AS` keyword is optional.